# Video working on iphone simulator but not in ipad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, video, swift3

In my app I have 2 videos. The first video plays perfectly in the iphone simulator and on my ipad. However the second video plays on the iphone simulator but not on my ipad. I dont know why this is happening. Any ideas?

The first video that works is jxdo11. The second video that does not work is j11. I have attached a pitcure of j11 on my ipad. [image: j11 pic; when button is pressed play j11]

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
let  moviePlayer =  AVPlayerViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func pc(_ sender: AnyObject) {
     playLocalVideo()
}

func playLocalVideo(){

    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jxdo11", ofType: "mp4"){
        let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)


        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)


        moviePlayer.player = player
        self.present(moviePlayer, animated: true) {
            self.moviePlayer.player!.play()
        }
    }

    else{
        print("Oops, something wrong when playing video.mp4")
    }
}


@IBAction func Mac(_ sender: AnyObject) {
     playLocalVideo1()
}
func playLocalVideo1(){

    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "j11", ofType: "mp4"){
        let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)


        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)


        moviePlayer.player = player
        self.present(moviePlayer, animated: true) {
            self.moviePlayer.player!.play()
        }
    }

    else{
        print("Oops, something wrong when playing video.mp4")
    }
}


  }
```

Comment: Not every video format plays on every device type. Maybe your iPad just can't play this video.

Comment: yeah but both files are mp4s one plays and the other does not.

Comment: Check the filename. Devices are case sensitive while the simulator usually isn't.

Comment: "yeah but both files are mp4s" But "mp4" tells us nothing. The _format_ of the video is a technical matter. "mp4" is just a general wrapper.